# I want my 2 Clickonce deployment URL's to launch the same app with different config files, but they are both launching the exact same app instead

Tags: .net, clickonce

I have a clickonce application and i want to deploy 2 versions of the same application with different config files. So the package is published from the same solution but with changed configs to different urls:
Example:
App1 is launched at http://myserver/app1/myapp.application and app2 is launched at http://myserver/app2/myapp.application

However both urls launch the same app (the latest one published). Is this correct? Can what i want to do be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio go into properties and change the names of the application or their GUIDs. Then the respective clients will treat the applications as completely independent.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to messing with the name or GUID is to bypass the actual app.config and use a simple XML file as the configuration. LINQ to XML makes this easy to do and you can key off of the executing context to pull the file location so the config files remain separate.

Answer (score 0):

Have a conditional test in the application for which URL it was launched from?